# JavaScript/jQuery datetime difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, date

I am trying to identify whether given date-time is future date and time or not.
For e.g. My current date time is '25-04-2010 08:26 PM' and if I pass '25-04-2010 09:00 PM' to a JavaScript function, then it should return me '1' if that date-time is future date & time otherwise it should return me '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do this using timestamp. So I just wrote below code.

```
var myDate = new Date("April 25, 2011 21:16:00"); // Your timezone!
var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000.0;
document.write(myEpoch);

var cur_date = new Date(); // Current date
var myEpoch1 = cur_date.getTime()/1000.0;
document.write("---"+myEpoch1);

var diff=myEpoch-myEpoch1; // If diff comes minus value, then it is past date-time, otherwise it is future data-time
alert(diff);
```

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2010,0,14);
var today = new Date();

if (myDate>today)
  {
  alert("Today is before 14th January 2010");
  }
else
  {
  alert("Today is after 14th January 2010");
  }
```

source: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score -3):

This seems like a simple parsing job to me. I won't give you the code, but will give you the approach.

1. Use split to split the string on ' ' (empty space)
2. Use split to split the first string [0] on '-'
3. Use split to split the second string [1] on ':'

-- Now simply concatenate all the strings in the order yyyymmddhhmmss

so your time string will become a signature like : 201004250900
and the second one becomes : 201003250826

Now simply do an integer compare ;)

This is the long winded approach

It just occurred to me that you should be able to parse the time string you're passing to date in javascript, and that makes your life easier... Try that.